# Spring Boot can't read docker-compose environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to achieve external configuration to set up a Spring Boot application (version 3.1.5) with `docker-compose`. The properties in my Spring Boot project's `application.yml` are as follows:

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://${EUREKA_URL:localhost}:8761/eureka
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: gamestore-backend
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: gamestore
      host: ${MONGO_URL:localhost}
      port: 27017
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 2GB
      max-request-size: 2GB
```

My project's `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
COPY target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
volumes:
  mongo-volume:
    driver: local

networks:
  springnet:
    name: springnet
    driver: bridge

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo-volume:/etc/mongo
    networks:
      - springnet
  eureka:
    container_name: eureka
    image: eureka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - springnet
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - springnet
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - mongo
    environment:
      EUREKA_URL: eureka
      MONGO_URL: mongo
```

After the deployment is done, I inspected the `backend` container and found that the environment variables are there:

```json
"Env": [
    "EUREKA_URL=eureka",
    "MONGO_URL=mongo",
    "PATH=/usr/java/openjdk-17/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/openjdk-17",
    "LANG=C.UTF-8",
    "JAVA_VERSION=17.0.2"
]
```

However, when I looked at the `backend` logs, I saw a lot of errors and the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1]
failed: Connection refused
```

Apparently, Spring hasn't replaced the value inside the `application.yml`. Here should be `http://eureka:8761`.

Why can't Spring find the variable? Any help would be appreciated.